# Paypal sdk for windows 10 app

Tags: paypal, microsoft-metro, paypal-sandbox, windows-10-universal

I am developing a Windows 10 app which needs to accept payments through Paypal. I googled for that Windows SDK but didn't find Paypal SDK or documentation related to that.

So if anyone implement that previously please help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

> I googled for that Windows SDK but didn't find Paypal SDK or documentation related to that.

There is no official SDK for integrating Paypal in an UWP app for now.

My suggestion is that you can try to use [Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/invoicing/) to implement Paypal in your app.